# What is "allocation context"?

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, allocation

I'm a student and I have to do a research about memory leak detection. In many papers they are talking about **allocation context**. I don't know what it means. I can't find any definition of **allocation context** (or translation, I'm from Germany).

As an example, a quote from a paper (Detecting Memory Leaks through Introspective Dynamic
Behavior Modeling using Machine Learning):

> The key idea behind using machine learning is that a leaking object is discernible by observing the lifetimes of other similar objects. That is, an object can be regarded as having leaked when it accrues a high degree of staleness that is not observed from other supposedly similar objects, i.e., objects with the same **allocation context**.

Or:

> To work around this, this work takes inspiration from previous research on object lifetime prediction [4, 20]. According to these works, the lifetime of an object is strongly correlated with its allocation context. Since the staleness of an object is bounded by its lifetime, object staleness is transitively correlated with **allocation context**.

Could someone explain it to me easy as possible?

EDIT:

The abstract:

> This paper expands staleness-based memory leak detection
>   by presenting a machine learning-based framework. The
>   proposed framework is based on an idea that object stal-
>   eness can be better leveraged in regard to similarity of ob-
>   jects; i.e., an object is more likely to have leaked if it shows
>   signicantly high staleness not observed from other similar
>   objects with the same **allocation context**.
>   A central part of the proposed framework is the modeling
>   of heap objects. To this end, the framework observes the
>   staleness of objects during a representative run of an ap-
>   plication. From the observed data, the framework generates
>   training examples, which also contain instances of hypothet-
>   ical leaks. Via machine learning, the proposed framework
>   replaces the error-prone user-denable staleness predicates
>   used in previous research with a model-based prediction.
>   The framework was tested using both synthetic and real-
>   world examples. Evaluation with synthetic leakage work-
>   loads of SPEC2006 benchmarks shows that the proposed
>   method achieves the optimal accuracy permitted by staleness-
>   based leak detection. Moreover, by incorporating 
>   **allocation context** into the model, the proposed method achieves
>   higher accuracy than is possible with object staleness alone.
>   Evaluation with real-world memory leaks demonstrates that
>   the proposed method is eective for detecting previously re-
>   ported bugs with high accuracy.

Comment: I'm not aware of any particular definition of the phrase "allocation context". For example, the phrase does not appear anywhere in the C standard. I think you'll just have to infer what it means from the *ahem* context in which the author used the phrase. Does the paper define the term?

Comment: Well, I've tried to find out from the context what allocation context could mean.. but without success.. the author does not define the term.. :/ i've added the abstract, where the term appears for the first time.. maybe it'll help..

Comment: It's possibly an established term in the specific field of memory leak detection. Digging through the references could be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've already searched all references for the keyword 'allocation context'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got a response from one of the authors. The definition is as follows:

**allocation context**

> It refers to the call stack contents at the time of an allocation.
>   For example, if an allocation site is contained in function foo and the
>   function is called from main (during the execution), the allocation context
>   for the allocation site is (main, main: call@foo, foo: malloc(...)).

Answer (score 6):

Consider such C [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak#A_simple_example_in_C):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void function_which_allocates(void) {
    /* allocate an array of 45 floats */
    float *a = malloc(sizeof(float) * 45);

    /* additional code making use of 'a' */

    /* return to main, having forgotten to free the memory we malloc'd */
}

int main(void) {
    function_which_allocates();

    /* the pointer 'a' no longer exists, and therefore cannot be freed,
     but the memory is still allocated. a leak has occurred. */
}
```

Allocation context of `a` is the `function_which_allocates`.

So, allocation context of a variable is the [scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_scope_rules.htm) of that variable.

If you are out of scope, you can't free that memory, which leads to memory leak.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make sense. Allocation context is a property of the memory block that was allocated, whereas scope is a property of the variable that points to it. The two are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it just means "the context in which it was allocated".
In other words, you can think of it as "the observable state of the program that when the allocation occurred" -- i.e., the call stack, local variables, etc.

Comment: I agree that "context", especially when talking about computer architecture, means very often the state of the program, content of registers, memory etc. But I think it's not the case in the text cited by OP. First sentence says *"objects with the same allocation context"*. With your definition of context, it's impossible. Two (or more) objects in their allocation moment couldn't have the same context (state of the program). Because when the first was allocated, the state changed.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk: Note that I said "**observable** state" for a good reason. Memory allocation is often treated as a pure (i.e., side-effect-free) operation, because generally it's hard to observe its side-effects, and you normally don't want to. (The only real way to do that is to exhaust your memory.) The only other observable state that differs after an allocation is the extra variable that points to the allocated block, which, for the purposes of "sameness", we can disregard here, because at that point it's unused and irrelevant to the rest of the program. (Also, nice revenge downvoting.)